# Android share comment on twitter

Tags: android, twitter

Android: I have a social networking application made by me, in which you can post comments, i want to facilitate user to one click share posted commented on user's twitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Twitter API](http://dev.twitter.com/) directly to do that.

There are also Twitter libraries compatible with Android platform.

- [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html)
- [JTwitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200505/simple-jtwitter-for-android-example)

Comment: Twitter4j not competebile with android udpate status throws status -1 but console app works fine.